# How do you find a normal vector of this set $T=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2 \leq 1, z=0 \}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vector-analysis

How do you find a normal vector of this set $T=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2 \leq 1, z=0 \}$?

The solution that my teacher has given is $(0, 0, -1)$, but I don't know how to find it. The vector must go downwards.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of the set $T$ on a 3d axis?  Then can you find a vector in 3d space that is perpendicular to $T$?  One hint is that $T$ lies completely on the $x-y$-plane

Comment: This is the unit disk lying in the plane $z=0$, so presumably you just find a vector normal to this plane.

Comment: Note that your surface is contained in the $xy$-plane, which should makes it rather trivial to determine the normal. Otherwise if you want an algorithmic way of doing it, you could parametrize the surface, differentiate with respect to each coordinate, and take the cross product of the resulting vectors.

Comment: Did your teacher have some further context? There are two possible normals. Is this surface supposed to be (part of) the boundary of something?

Comment: Is (x, y, 0) a correct parametrization? Because if I do the vector product, gives me the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to visualize the surface.  Sketch it.  In this case you have a disk on the xy plane.  What is perpendicular to this disk?

If you are unable to visualize your surface, can you paramerize it?

Suppose you have $x = u(s,t), y = v(s,t), z = w(s,t)$

The vector $(\frac {\partial x}{\partial s},\frac {\partial y}{\partial s}, \frac {\partial z}{\partial s})$ will be a vector parallel to the surface.  As will $(\frac {\partial x}{\partial t},\frac {\partial y}{\partial t}, \frac {\partial z}{\partial t})$

Their cross product will be normal to the surface.

More tools:

If you have $z = f(x,y)$ then you can use $x,y$ as your parameters.

$(\frac {\partial x}{\partial x},\frac {\partial y}{\partial x}, \frac {\partial z}{\partial x}) = (1,0,\frac {\partial z}{\partial x})\\
(\frac {\partial x}{\partial y},\frac {\partial y}{\partial y}, \frac {\partial z}{\partial y}) = (0,1,\frac {\partial z}{\partial x})\\
(1,0,\frac {\partial z}{\partial x})\times(0,1,\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}) = (-\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}, 1)$

Finally, if you have $F(x,y,z) = k, \nabla F$ will be normal to your surface.

Answer (score 0):

The surface $T$ is contained in the $xy-$plane, right? And the vectors $v=(1,0,0)\,w=(0,1,0)$ belong to the surface $T$, right? Hence a vector $n$ normal to $T$ is orthogonal to both vectors. $n$ is equal to $w\times v$. Notice that also $v\times w$ is normal.